why my code is not checking email id when signing up
I am trying to implement sign up with google in next.js. I want to apply a check if the entered email id is already present in the firebase authentication. it should alert the user and move the user to sign-in page.
    const signInWithGoogle = async () => {
    const auth = getAuth(app);
    const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
    try {
      const email = await getEmailFromGooglePopup(provider);
      const signInMethods = await fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(auth, email);
  
      if (signInMethods.length > 0) {
        console.log('User already signed up');
        router.push('/sign-in');
      } else {
        const result = await signInWithPopup(auth, provider);
        console.log({ result });
        sessionStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(result.user));
        router.push('/');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.code === 'auth/popup-blocked') {
        alert("Popup blocked. Please enable popups for this site and try again.");
      } else {
        console.error("Error checking sign-in methods or signing in with Google:", error.message);
      }
    }
  };
  
  const getEmailFromGooglePopup = async (provider) => {
    const auth = getAuth(app);
    try {
      const result = await signInWithPopup(auth, provider);
      const email = result.user.email;
      await signOut(auth);
      return email;
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error("Error getting email from Google popup: " + error.message);
    }
  };

But i am incurring a problem -
page.jsx:14 Warning: Cannot update a component (`Router`) while rendering a different component (`Home`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `Home`, follow the stack trace as described in https://reactjs.org/link/setstate-in-render
    at Home (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./app/page.jsx:21:91)
    at StaticGenerationSearchParamsBailoutProvider (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/static-generation-searchparams-bailout-provider.js:16:11)
    at InnerLayoutRouter (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:242:11)
    at RedirectErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:74:9)
    at RedirectBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:82:11)
    at NotFoundErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:76:9)
    at NotFoundBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:84:11)
    at LoadingBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:340:11)
    at ErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:162:11)
    at InnerScrollAndFocusHandler (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:152:9)
    at ScrollAndFocusHandler (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:227:11)
    at RenderFromTemplateContext (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/render-from-template-context.js:16:44)
    at OuterLayoutRouter (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:359:11)
    at body
    at html
    at RedirectErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:74:9)
    at RedirectBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:82:11)
    at NotFoundErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:76:9)
    at NotFoundBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:84:11)
    at DevRootNotFoundBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/dev-root-not-found-boundary.js:33:11)
    at ReactDevOverlay (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/internal/ReactDevOverlay.js:84:9)
    at HotReload (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/hot-reloader-client.js:307:11)
    at Router (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js:182:11)
    at ErrorBoundaryHandler (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:115:9)
    at ErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:162:11)
    at AppRouter (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js:542:13)
    at ServerRoot (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/app-index.js:129:11)
    at RSCComponent
    at Root (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/app-index.js:145:11)

It shows me the google emails stored in my pc. but when clicked on an email which is already registered. it is not giving me any alert and nor moving me to sign-in page.

where in the code are you navigating to the sign-in page?

@PeterHaddad 10th line - router.push('/sign-in');
